# If three of multiple conditions match

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I'm learning JavaScript, by trying to build a pure JavaScript search engine. It is fairly good now. But I want to still imrpove it. Part of the code that I want to modify is the following:

```
for (i = 0; i < t.length; i++){
if (
t[i].toUpperCase().indexOf(k[0]) > -1
&&
t[i].toUpperCase().indexOf(k[1]) > -1
&&
t[i].toUpperCase().indexOf(k[2]) > -1
&&
t[i].toUpperCase().indexOf(k[3]) > -1
&&
t[i].toUpperCase().indexOf(k[4]) > -1
&&
t[i].toUpperCase().indexOf(k[5]) > -1
&&
t[i].toUpperCase().indexOf(k[6]) > -1
&&
t[i].toUpperCase().indexOf(k[7]) > -1
)
{code to execute here}
}
```

Where `k` is the spitted query string the user searches:

```
var q = decodeURI(window.location.href.replace(/(^.+html\?|^.+html)/,'').replace(/\+/g,' ')).trim().replace(/\s/g,'+');
var k = q.split("+");

<form onsubmit="ah1(); return false;">
<input id="in1" type="text" maxlength="255" placeholder="Words to search" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="" />
</form>

<script>function ah1(){
window.location.href = "search.html?" + document.getElementById("in1").value.trim().replace(/\s/g,"+");}</script>
```

`t` is the data to search in, stored in an external JS file in an array:

```
var t = ['some words','some other words','etc'];
```

Now I want to modify the above condition so that instead of all seven filters, it returns true if, say, at least three of them match.
Do I have to set them one by one Like the following

```
else{if (
t[i].toUpperCase().indexOf(k[0]) > -1
&&
t[i].toUpperCase().indexOf(k[1]) > -1
&&
t[i].toUpperCase().indexOf(k[2]) > -1
)
{code to execute here}
}
```

Any idea to get it working by shortest possible piece of code.

Comment: please add some search words(?) and the wanted outcomes as well.

Comment: I'd highly recommend using sensible variable names - single-letter variable names are **very** hard to understand by others (and by you when you read your code later). Eg you might consider `dataToSearch` instead of `t[i]` and `wordsToFind` instead of `k`

Comment: @NinaScholz, the outcome is a list that match the search words: `var p = "\n"; var result = p += '<li>' + t[i] + '</li>';`

Comment: please add some example. to read somenones cod is easier with knowing the **input** and wanted **output**. if i would ask a question, i would add all necessary parameters to make an answer easy to give. in this spirit, add some use cases and what you like to achieve. please have a look here, too: [mcve]

Comment: @CertainPerformance, shall I edit my post?

Comment: @NinaScholz, I edited my question. I hope it is clear somehow now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a variable for the minimum count and one for found words. Then check if the found words coiunt is equal to the wanted count and return the phrase.

```js
var t = ['one two three four five six', 'one two three four five', 'one two three four', 'one two three', 'one two'],
    k = ['one', 'three', 'four', 'five'],
    min = 3,
    result = t.filter(phrase => {
        var count = 0;
        return k.some(word => phrase.includes(word) && ++count === min);
    });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Just count them

Loop over the .indexOf(k[***something***]) variables and count how many of them fulfil your condition.

After that, compare the count to three.

Comment: It seems good but tricky. Could you please show me an example?